# Vim shows line numbers like 493-494

Tags: shell, unix, vim

Vim shows line numbers as `493-494`. What does this mean?

Also running `awk '{length($0)>493}' file_name` doesn't  shows up this line.

Can some one please explain me this behavior?

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: This doesn't make sense you are comparing line numbers to line length. My guess, you have tabs on that line.

Comment: Do you mean column offset? Maybe it should be `byte offset`-`column offset`.

Comment: when and where did you see the `m-n` numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing line numbers with columns.

Given a file like:

```
abcd
ab☠d
```

If the cursor is in the last character of the first line you will see:

```
1,4
```

So that is line number and column number.

However if the cursor is in the last character of the second line you will see:

```
2,6-4
```

So that means: second line, sixth byte, fourth column/character. This is because in this line there are characters that take more than one byte.